# How to open old Microsoft Office files using the exact formatting as they were created with?

Tags: microsoft-office, text-formatting, documents, microsoft-office-2003

I have a bunch of old .doc and .ppt files from around 2004, created with Microsoft Office 2003 (or Microsoft Office XP, but I think it was 2003. Is there a way to check this?) and I would like to open these using the exact same formatting as they were created with. I installed Office 2003 on Windows XP, which I'm pretty sure is the setup they were created with, but the formatting is still off. I don't recall having installed extra fonts, so I doubt there are fonts missing. How can I open these files using the intended formatting? Can I check with what settings the files were created (fonts, markup, etc.) and replicate these?

Comment: I have found your problem in the past when moving between MSOffice versions. Indeed, I found that Office products from other manufacturers were more compatible with old MSOffice files than later MS releases. I didn't find a solution: in many instances I was able to continue using the original software for those files; otherwise, I was forced to import into the later release and reformat manually.

Comment: Word's formating is based on the metrics for the printer used when it was saved, so if you open old documents on a system with (a) different printer(s) they may format somewhat differently.